# Radio button functionality for iOS/Android

Tags: android, ios, radio-buttons

I need to create settings for token (crypto wallet) for iOS and Android.

For desktop we create toggles/switchers:

- regular / max privacy
- one-time use / permanent

[image]

Now we need to transfer these settings to mobile app design. Also it shouldn't be hidden (e.g as s list).

Current version is below. But we are looking for the better variant.

[image]

Comment: Hey Dasha,
why are you unsatisfied with your current design? What could be better? It is unclear from your question what you are struggling with.

Comment: Hi Nash! The issue is: current "chips" design looks like buttons in our app. We want to make it more as "chips". And we think it can make user do not understand that this is a choice (radio button)

Answer (score 1):

The main part about the design that is unclear is that there is no "inactive" state for the not selected radio button. So it is not possible to draw a mental connection between the two options, beside the proximity.

It simply needs a visual cue that these two elements are mutually exclusive, that's what normal radio buttons do with the dot and the empty container:

[image]

So adding some simple visual cues like these would help massively:

[image]

---

**Edit:** Only now took a better look at the desktop design, which does exactly this. Why not use the same element on mobile?

Comment: thanks =) we decided to do the same way)